# Find all ports a process in Solaris is listening to

Tags: process, port, solaris, netstat, lsof

I need to list all ports that a process in Solaris is listening to (similar to 'lsof -i -P' in Linux). Unfortunately the lsof command doesn't work, and I can't install it either. Is there any options? I've tried some netstat commands, but that doesn't show the port or pid.

Comment: Did our answers below help you? Let us know if you need more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a nice script using the command pfiles:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/security/pcp-149863.txt

Vince

Comment: This script uses the `pfiles` command to inspect a given process. This command will temporarily halt the process in order to inspect it. I have on one occasion seen a process that could not cope with this (it would core dump). This may be very rare, dunno. From Solaris 11.2 onwards you can also use `netstat -u` but I'm unaware if that command is any different, i.e. if it also temporarily halts the process.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`pfiles`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29030/pfiles-1.html#scrolltoc)

> pfiles
>
> Report fstat(2) and fcntl(2) information for all open files in each process. For network endpoints, the local (and peer if connected)
>   address information is also provided. For sockets, the socket type,
>   socket options and send and receive buffer sizes are also provided. In
>   addition, a path to the file is reported if the information is
>   available from /proc/pid/path. This is not necessarily the same name
>   used to open the file. See proc(4) for more information.